# UWSGI server active failed when enabling uwsgi server in centor

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I am following a [tutorial](https://mitchjacksontech.github.io/How-To-Flask-Python-Centos7-Apache-uWSGI/) to deploy a flask application using uwsgi server.

Flask app - `flaskdemo.py`-

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def root():
    return "You have found somewhere on your road to nowhere.<br>Congrats"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

`uwsgi.py`

```
from flaskdemo import app as application

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run()
```

`flaskdemo.ini`

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi

master = true
processes = 5

socket = 127.0.0.1:8000
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
```

Everything was fine till this point and the app was running fine.

`flaskdemo.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI server for flaskdemo
After=network.target

[Service]
User=flaskdemo
Group=apache
WorkingDirectory=/home/flaskdemo/flaskdemo
Environment="PATH=/home/flaskdemo/flaskdemo/env/bin"
ExecStart=/home/flaskdemo/flaskdemo/env/bin/uwsgi --ini flaskdemo.ini

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After creating the service and starting the service, status of the service is as of follows:

```
comission_project.service - uWSGI instance to serve myproject
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/comission_project.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2021-08-08 19:25:45 IST; 14s ago
 Main PID: 9263 (code=exited, status=217/USER)

Aug 08 19:25:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started uWSGI instance to serve myproject.
Aug 08 19:25:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: comission_project.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=217/USER
Aug 08 19:25:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: comission_project.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

And the app also stopped working

Comment: The output of systemctl you posted is truncated. Please update your post. You can also try `journalctl -u  flaskdemo.service` for more details.

Comment: @Anonymous  I have updated the error message

Comment: Code 217 suggests that the user for your systemd service (flaskdemo) does not exist. Make sure the user exists and that it indeed owns '/home/flaskdemo' (maybe you created this directory manually ?)